# How to set status code to 404 whenever a promise is rejected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, routes

I am verifying login functionality by using promises and chaining them. When user enters invalid password, rejecting the data or else resolving it. At the end i am verifying if user is logged in successfully by chaining these methods.

```
 let verifyData = (req, res) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (req.body.name) {
        userModel.findOne({ name: req.body.name }).exec((err, result) => {
          if (result) {
            resolve(result);
          } else {
            reject(err);
          }
        });
      } else {
        let apiResponse = response.generate(
          false,
          null,
          404,
          "Mandatory fields missing, Please provide your userId and password"
        );

        reject(apiResponse);
      }
    });
  };
```

Is there a way i can send status code as 404 whenever data is rejected?
This is causing an issue as currently i am getting 200 status code for rejected data

```
  verifyData(req, res).then(validatePassword).then((result) => {res.send(result);})
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status

```
  verifyData(req, res).then(validatePassword).then((result) => {res.send(result);})
    .catch((err) => {
      const status = err.STATUS_PROP; // get status from apiResponse
      // or
      const status = 400

      res.status(status).send(err);
    });
```